# Swift compiler Warning Converting function value of type @MainActor loses global actor MainActor

Tags: swiftui, onchange, searchable, mainactor

I am using Swift UI. I created simple search function to filter the data. OnChnage function I am calling the State property wrapper with view model search function. I done some research that , the data should receive into main thread and that the main reason I have annotated the function with @MainActor but still I got same warning.

Here is the search function code with view model.

```
@MainActor
final class ProductListViewModel {

    @Published private(set) var productLists: [Product] = []
    @Published private var filteredProductLists: [Product] = []

    private let repository: ProductRepository
    init(repository: ProductRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }
}
extension ProductListViewModel: ProductListViewModelAction {
    func getProductList(urlStr: String) async {
            guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else {
            self.customError = NetworkError.invalidURL
            return
        }
        do {
            let lists = try await repository.getList(for: url)
            productLists = lists.products

        } catch {
          // catching the error 
        }
    }
}

extension ProductListViewModel {
    @MainActor
    func performSearch(keyword: String) {
        filteredProductLists = productLists.filter { product in
            product.title.contains(keyword)
        }
    }
    var productList: [Product] {
        filteredProductLists.isEmpty ? productLists: filteredProductLists
    }
}
```

Here is my view code ..

```
    struct ProductListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProductListViewModel(repository: ProductRepositoryImplementation(networkManager: NetworkManager()))
    @State var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.customError != nil && !viewModel.refreshing {
                    alertView()
                } else {
                    if viewModel.refreshing {
                        progressView()
                    }
                    if viewModel.productLists.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {

                        List(viewModel.productList, id: \.self) { product in
                            ProductListViewCell(productData: product)

                        } .listStyle(.grouped)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .onChange(of: searchText, perform: viewModel.performSearch)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    getToolBarView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Product List"))
        }.task {
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
        .refreshable {
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
    }

    func getDataFromAPI() async {
        await viewModel.getProductList(urlStr: NetworkURL.productUrl)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func getToolBarView() -> some View {
        Button {
            Task{
                await getDataFromAPI()
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    .padding(.all, 10.0)
            }.fixedSize()
        }
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func progressView() -> some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(height: 180)
                .overlay {
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView().padding(50)
                        Text("Please Wait Message").font(.headline)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func alertView() -> some View {
        Text("").alert(isPresented: $viewModel.isErrorOccured) {
            Alert(title: Text("General_Error"), message: Text(viewModel.customError?.localizedDescription ?? ""),dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
        }
    }
}
```

Error on changes with onChange(of: searchText) { viewModel.performSearch(keyword: searchText) } ..

[image]
Here is the screenshot of the warning ..

[image: warning]

Comment: This code doesn't compile. For example `.task {
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }` is attached to brackets belonging to `var body: some View`

Comment: I have removed lost of unnecessary code which is not related with this question . That why you see only one { not there @timbretimbre

Comment: Let me share the entire view

Comment: The entire view code is added now @timbretimbre

Comment: have you tried using `.onChange(of: searchText) { viewModel.performSearch(keyword: searchText) }`

Comment: the changes rise following error.. Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '()' and Type '()' cannot conform to 'Equatable' on .searchable(text: $searchText) @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: I have added the screenshot.. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: I'm assuming you are using ios17. Otherwise use `.onChange(of: searchText) { val in
                viewModel.performSearch(keyword: val)
            }` for ios16

Comment: I am using 16.2. the minimum deployment target

Comment: I have called the search function inside the DispatchQueue.main.async or @MainActor but still get same warning.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is for running an external action, to transform data you should use a computed property into a subview, e.g.

```
ProductList(products: filteredProducts)
```

```
var filteredProducts: [Product] {
    products.filter { product in
        product.title.contains(searchText)
    }
}
```

Also you need a do/catch inside the `.task` so you can set an `@State` to the error. Also you need `@State` to hold the product lists downloaded. Basically remove the view model object, the `View` struct already is main actor there is no need for a main actor object and will just slow things down/cause consistency bugs. You would benefit from making `repository` an `EnvironmentKey` so you can easily replace it with one containing sample data for previews.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but ALL the business logic is placed into view model as far is the MVVM architecture pattern is concern. I have the property into view model and calling it into view .

Comment: It's SwiftUI so the `View` struct is your view model already you don't need another one.

Comment: I disagree. The view can not be considered as view model

Comment: It's not the "view" though - it's a hierarchy of view-data structs. SwiftUI diffs these view-data structs and then renders the actual view layer automatically for you, i.e. it inits/updates/deinits UIKit UIView objects.